# Formatação condicional em um gridView

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

Tenho um `gridView` onde é carregado, do meu `SQLServer`, todas as informações do banco.

A minha pergunta é a seguinte. tem como mudar a cor da fonte quando uma data é menor que a data do sistema (por exemplo, colocar a vermelho as contas que estão vencidas)?

Segue o meu código para carregar o `gridView` e a tela:

```
private void CarregarGridContasPagarAberto()
{

    IList<ContasPagarDTO> listaContasPagar = new List<ContasPagarDTO>();
    listaContasPagar = new ContasPagarModel().CargaContasPagarAberto();

    dgvContasPagar.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
    dgvContasPagar.DataSource = listaContasPagar;
}
```

tela:

[image: Grid]

```
private void dgvContasPagar_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs Arguments)
{
    IList<ContasPagarDTO> listaContasPagar = new List<ContasPagarDTO>();
    listaContasPagar = new ContasPagarModel().CargaContasPagarAberto();

    if (this.dgvContasPagar.Columns[Arguments.ColumnIndex].Name == "DtVencContas")
    {
       // return;

       var Conta = listaContasPagar[Arguments.RowIndex];

       if(Conta.DtVencContas < DateTime.Now)
           Arguments.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Red;
       else
           Arguments.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Black;
    }
}
```

[image: Resultado do Grid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o evento CellFormating.

```
private void DataGridView1_CellFormatting (object Sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs Arguments)
{
    if (this.DataGridView1.Columns [Arguments.ColumnIndex].Name != "Sua Coluna Aqui")
        return;

    var Conta = ListaContasPagar [Arguments.RowIndex];

    if (DateTime.Now < Conta.DataDaConta)
        Arguments.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
    else
        Arguments.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

Comment: editei a minha pergunta com o erro veja se faltou algo

Comment: Muda o "DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e" para "DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs Arguments".

Comment: Não deu certo não muda a cor e da um erro 
Additional information: Não é possível converter um objeto do tipo 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' no tipo 'System.IConvertible'.

Comment: Você ta tentando converter a coluna (sendo que ela é um objeto mas não o valor) pra datetime na condição if, repara que eu criei a variavel Conta pra pegar o valor da célula, usa essa variavel pra comparar a data.

Comment: Muito Obrigado Alexandre me ajudou D+, editei a minha pergunta com o código e a tela do resultado –